# Python discord.py on_reaction_removed() not called

Tags: python, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot. I have the following code:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    print("on_reaction_add called")

@client.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
    print("on_reaction_remove called")

# same problem if I remove this part
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    print("on_raw_reaction_remove called")
```

However, if I start the bot and react to a event, then remove the reaction again, I see:

```
on_reaction_add called
on_raw_reaction_remove called
```

As you can see, `on_reaction_remove` is never called. I must have the correct permissions since `on_reaction_add()`  works properly. This also means the message must be in the message cache, since otherwise `on_reaction_add`  would not work either. `on_raw_reaction_remove` is still called, so it must have properly detected that I removed a reaction.

Note that even if I don't include the `on_raw_reaction_remove` event I get the same problem.

Is there a problem with my code, is this a problem with discord.py or is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: Why are you using `on_reaction_remove()` and `on_reaction_add()` instead of `on_raw_reaction_remove()` and `on_raw_reaction_add()` in the first place?

Comment: @MrMetacom It is very convenient to be able to access the message, and I only care about recent messages anyway so it's not a problem if reactions get missed before the bot starts up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, unlike `on_reaction_add`, `on_reaction_remove` requires that both the *message* and the *user* can be found in the cache.

Luckily, ensuring every user is in the cache is quite simple. You will need the `Intents.members` intent enabled on your bot so it can pre-fetch the list of channel members on startup, and `on_reaction_remove` can be called properly.

See the recently added [comment in the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_remove)

Answer (score -2):

If you read the documentation of `on_raw_reaction_remove` you will notice something, it says:

Called when a message has a reaction added. Unlike on_reaction_add(), this is called regardless of the **state of the internal message cache.**

That means, raw events are called even message is not in bot's cache, whereas normal reactions are called when message is in the bot's cache.

That is the problem, the message you are removing reaction from is not in bot's cache so it does not trigger normal event, but it does trigger raw event.

Comment: Ok, but why is `on_reaction_add` called then? Doesn't that depend on the same cache? The message in question has been posted by the bot only a few seconds before, the cache shouldn't expire that fast

Comment: are you using latest discord.py?

Comment: I'm using version 1.5.1, I believe that is currently the latest version